# Why is self-intersection not allowed with continuous transformations?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

A function $f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism if it has the following properties:

1)$f$ is bijection

2)$f$ is continuous

3)$f^{-1}$ is continuous.

And now let's say we have two letters from alphabet.

My book says that if, using continuous transformations, you can make one letter match without self-intersection or cutting into another, then they are homeomorphic.

[image]

Here is an example

Now maybe it is obvious, but why is self-intersection not allowed with continuous transformations? I mean if we do the transformation, and that letter intersects itself, why is that not a continuous transformation?

Edit.

This is example where it has self-intersection.Why here map is not bijective?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-intersection would mean $f$ is not bijective - two points map to the same point. I will try to give an example.

Imagine a line of length one, say the interval $[0,1]$. This is very easily bijective with the letter $U$, simply by "curving" the unit line. However, let us say we continue curving the sides of $U$ until they intersect, forming some sort of upright $\alpha$. If we keep our transformation from $[0,1]$ in mind, and starting from one end of our $\alpha$, when we pass the intersection point the first time, we could associate some number from the interval $[0,1]$, corresponding to how far we have walked. Say, $\frac13$. Now, we keep walking, and the next time we pass the intersection point, we may assign a new number to the intersection, say $\frac23$. This walk is supposed to be our homeomorphy from $\alpha$ to $[0,1]$, but as we have seen, it is not injective, thus not bijective: Indeed, $f(\frac13)=f(\frac23)=*$, where $*$ is the intersection point.

This indicates that closed loops are intrinsic and an important property - which will become apparent when you start looking at fundamental groups and homotopy.

Comment: I don't get why it isn't bijective?

Comment: I edited my post with an example of self-intersection.Can you please explain on that example?

Comment: I will try to clarify in my answer.

Comment: But in my example I still didn't get why it is not bijective

Comment: It is the same situation: The final arrow is not an injective transformation, as it takes two points and puts them on top of each other.

Comment: But what if in your example you let's say correspond $\frac{1}{3}$ for intersection point and then when second time you  pass intersection point again you correspond same $\frac{1}{3}$ not $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: I understand now thank you very much